# NodeJS Populating an array from recursive-readdir

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm new to promises and I know the issue is that I'm trying to read the array **before** the promises have resolved. If I just console.log the files they print fine, just need them in an array so I can iterate through them.

Can someone nudge me in the right direction? I'm using the recursive-readdir node module to grab a list of all files within the dir1 and dir2 directories and add them to an array (var sitemap).

```
var recursive = require("recursive-readdir");

var directories = ['dir1', 'dir2'];
var sitemap = [];
for(var i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
    recursive(directories[i], ["*.pdf", "*.json", "*.xml", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.png", "*.css", "*.js", "*.flv", "*.swf", "*.ttf", "*.pptx", "*.doc", "*.docx"], function (err, files) {
        for(var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            let url = 'example.com/' + files[x];
            addURL(url);
        }
    });
}

function addURL(url) {
    sitemap.push(url);
}

// Returns empty array
console.log(sitemap);
```

Comment: you are using callback approach where's according to your needs you should be using promise based.

Comment: I had tried the recursive promise approach described in the documentation and I end up in the same place. I don't know if I'm still not accessing the resolved promise correctly and that's why I'm not seeing a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will work, added console.log(sitemap) in Promise, please check

```js
const recursive = require("recursive-readdir");

const directories = ['dir1', 'dir2'];
const sitemap = [];


const extns = ["*.pdf", "*.json", "*.xml", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.png", "*.css", "*.js", "*.flv", "*.swf", "*.ttf", "*.pptx", "*.doc", "*.docx"];


const allRequests = directories.map((item) => {
  return recursive(item, extns);
});

Promise.all(allRequests).then((files) => {
  for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
    let url = 'example.com/' + files[x];
    addURL(url);
  }
  console.log(sitemap);
});

function addURL(url) {
  sitemap.push(url);
}


//console.log(sitemap);
```

Here is one of the approach using promise...will put up a better approach to handle multiple directories..

```js
var recursive = require("recursive-readdir");

var directories = ['dir1', 'dir2'];
var sitemap = [];


const extns = ["*.pdf", "*.json", "*.xml", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.png", "*.css", "*.js", "*.flv", "*.swf", "*.ttf", "*.pptx", "*.doc", "*.docx"];
const path1 = recursive(directories[0], extns);
const path2 = recursive(directories[1], extns);

Promise.all([path1, path2]).then(function(files) {
  for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
    let url = 'example.com/' + files[x];
    addURL(url);
  }
console.log(sitemap);
});

function addURL(url) {
  sitemap.push(url);
}


//console.log(sitemap);
```

Comment: Hey @Anirudh, I tried both of your suggestions but unfortunately they give me the same result as the code I posted. The sitemap array isn't populated (at least by the time console.log(sitemap) is called.

Comment: @Jeff console.log(sitemap); should be added in the Promise call...please check the above code..it should work....sorry I missed it earlier

Comment: No worries. So will the console.log(sitemap) just log the value after the promise resolves? I need the sitemap array populated with the resolved promise values so I can pass it to another function. I think my issues is that I'm trying to do something synchronously with async functions.

Comment: Yes you need to do it after promise has resolved...you can call the function inside Promise same as the console.log...

Comment: I might not be understanding, so I need to nest my other calls inside of the promise? The next function I want to run also returns a promise. So how do I keep everything from just nesting inside each of the promises?